# Prove a finite sum equals to zero

Tags: summation

I am trying to prove the following expression

$$\sum_{n=1}^{N}\prod_{m=1, m \neq n}^{N} \frac{1}{\frac{1}{x_m}-\frac{1}{x_n}}=0.   $$  (1)

I have used an inductive approach to prove (1). In particular, when N= 2 or N=3, it is readily that (1) holds. However, when assuming that (1) holds for N = M, it becomes complicated to evaluate and confirm that (1) holds for N = M+1.

Does anyone have suggestions/advices for proving (1)?

Thank you.

Comment: Hmm.... I might try to switch the product and summation. You might be able to do this directly (try some smaller examples and check) or you could turn the product into a sum by taking logs

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions :)

Answer (score 2):

This is
$$\sum_{n=1}^N\prod_{m:m\ne n}\frac1{a_m-a_n}$$
where $a_m=1/x_m$. By Lagrange interpolation, 
$$1=\sum_{n=1}^N\prod_{m:m\ne n}\frac{x-a_n}{a_m-a_n}.$$
Compare coefficients of $x^{N-1}$ (as long as $N\ge2$).

ADDED IN EDIT

Lagrange interpolation finds the unique polynomial of degree
at most $N-1$ with $f(a_1)=b_1,\ldots,f(a_N)=b_n$ with $a_1,\ldots,a_N$
distinct. It is
$$\sum_{n=1}^N\prod_{m:m\ne n}b_n\frac{x-a_n}{a_m-a_n}.$$
The proof is straightforward: insert $a_n$ for $x$ and all but
the $n$-th term vanishes, and that term reduces to $b_n$.

Comment: Thank you for your hint. I am trying to connect your guide to the solution of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Let $z_n=\frac{1}{x_n}$ be arbitrary (different) complex numbers. Your sum is (up to the sign, $(-1)^{N-1}$)
$$\sum^N_{n=1}\frac{1}{\omega'(z_n)},$$ where $\omega(z)=(z-z_1)\ldots(z-z_N)$. But that's the sum of the residues of $\frac{1}{\omega(z)}$, i.e. it's equal to
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|z|=R}\frac{dz}{\omega(z)},$$
if $R$ is large enough for the circle to contain all $z_n$. But the integral is of order $O(R^{-N+1})$ for large $R$, so the sum must be zero.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.